# How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have two lists that I have confirmed are the same length. I want to operate on them at the same time. My code currently looks something like this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, 6];
var c = [];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  c.add(new Foo(a, b));
}
```

It seems a bit clunky to count up to the length of list A in this fashion. Is there a nicer and more Dart-y way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at the `quiver` package's [`zip` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/zip.html).

You could write this as:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, 6];
var c = [];
for (var pair in zip([a, b])) {
  c.add(new Foo(pair[0], pair[1]));
}
```

Comment: Link is broken, good answer though after looking it up it solved my issue.

Comment: Link is fine again : - )

Answer (score 22):

There's a [collection package by the Dart Team](https://pub.dev/packages/collection/) which has a class [IterableZip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableZip-class.html):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

final a = [1, 2, 3];
final b = [4, 5, 6];
List<Foo> c = [];
for (final pairs in IterableZip([a, b])) {
  c.add(Foo(pairs[0], pairs[1]));
}
```

Some more notes:

- `package:collection/iterable_zip.dart` is deprecated, you'd need to import simply the `collection.dart` like shown.
- `final a` and `final b` variables will have inferred template list types. I have not specified template type for `IterableZip`, but in some cases (in a complex case where I used it) you may need to explicitly type it like `IterableZip<int>`, so in the loop you can more conveniently access the members. In this simple case the compiler/interpreter can infer the type easily.
- The package is not part of the core Dart, but it does not require Flutter: in case of a Dart project you install it by [dart pub add collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install)

Comment: This is appropriate for Flutter users, but is not part of raw dart.

Comment: @Thelema Correct, it's not part of the core dart, however several other answers also advise packages. In case of Dart you'd say `dart pub add collection`, so it does not require Flutter (see https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install). However I need to correct my answer because it's also not part of the core Flutter.

Comment: I'd also emphasize that the collection package is distributed by the Dart team.

Comment: I stand corrected; this is a reasonable solution for even non-Flutter users of Dart.

Answer (score 7):

Now that we have list comprehensions in dart:

```
final c = [for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i+= 1) Foo(a[i], b[i])];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var c = List.generate(a.length, (i) => Foo(a[i], b[i]));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an even shorter solution using the `quiver` package's `zip` function, you can do the following:

```
final c = zip([a, b]).map((item) => Foo(item[0], item[1])).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it:

```dart
class IterableImpl<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  final Iterator<T> Function() _iterator;

  IterableImpl(this._iterator);

  @override
  Iterator<T> get iterator => _iterator();
}

class IteratorImpl<T> extends Iterator<T> {
  final T Function() _current;
  final bool Function() _moveNext;

  IteratorImpl(this._current, this._moveNext);

  @override
  T get current => _current();

  @override
  bool moveNext() => _moveNext();
}

IterableImpl<T> zip2<T, A, B>(
  Iterable<A> a,
  Iterable<B> b,
  T Function(A a, B b) combine,
) =>
    IterableImpl(
      () {
        final itA = a.iterator;
        final itB = b.iterator;

        return IteratorImpl(
          () => combine(itA.current, itB.current),
          () => itA.moveNext() && itB.moveNext(),
        );
      },
    );
```

And then:

```dart
void main() {
  final a = [ 1, 2,  3, 4];
  final b = [-1, 0, 10];

  final x = zip2(a, b, (a, b) => a * b);

  print(x.toList()); // prints [-1, 0, 30]
}
```

No external libs used.

Answer (score 0):

i also find solution like this and i done for me like this.
without any lib

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [4, 5, 6];
var c = [];
a.forEach((element) {

c.add(new Foo(element,b[a.indexOf(element)]));

});
```

this works for me as i want. Hope for you also

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of `zip` sets the types correctly and it's so short that you can just drop it in any part of your code without having to pull in a dependency.

```
class Pair<A, B> {
  const Pair(this.a, this.b);

  final A a;
  final B b;
}

Iterable<Pair<A, B>> zip<A, B>(List<A> listA, List<B> listB) sync* {
  assert(
    listA.length == listB.length,
    'For zipping, lengths of the lists must match',
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
    yield Pair(listA[i], listB[i]);
  }
}
```